# Table Update with this error "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 8, file "test")"

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am writing a script to copy the values from the sheet "Test" to "Master List".
It is supposed to find the last row of master list and add to the next empty row.

```
function test() {
  var ss =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST");
  var range = ss.getRange("A72:I81");
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Master List");
  var topleftcell = destination.getRange("A1");
  topleftcell.activate();
  var lastRow = destination.getLastRow()
  range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 1, 10, lastRow+1, 9);
  range.copyFormatToRange(destination, 1, 10, lastRow+1, 9);

}
```

It managed to run a few times then the error occurred "We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try again. (line 8, file "test")"

Can anyone advise me what's wrong with the codes? How to rectify this?

Comment: Did you waited a bit and tried again?

Comment: I tried again after 9 hours, the same error message occurred. :(

Comment: If the code worked, then stopped without you changing anything, you might consider reporting it on the [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list)  Just make sure that you can duplicate the problem.  If you can't get it work, there are alternatives that you can use, `getValues()` and `setValues()`.